# Meteor template Blaze how to return only first element of array

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

For example I have an array: var arr = ['a', 'b'] and want to get only first element in template

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `{{arr.[0]}}`. And this is now at least 30 characters.

https://www.blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Identifiers-and-Paths

Comment: @BoumTAC, Clarification: You need to have a helper (or a field in the data context) named `arr` that returns the array.