# meteor display first element of array in template spacebars

Tags: javascript, arrays, templates, meteor, spacebars

I want to display in my template only the first element of an array. I've seen many topics including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630316/meteor-template-blaze-how-to-return-only-first-element-of-array) but it doesn't work in my case.

I have an helper like this:

```
Template.home.helpers({
  posts() {
    return Posts.find({});
  }
});
```

I would like to do something like this in my template:

```
{{posts.[0].title}}
```

I don't want to use a findOne in this case.

Comment: it should work. Are you sure it is not caused by already existing variable posts in data context or other name conflict?
Or using it before collection is ready so it errors cause there is no such array in time of execution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to do this at the helper level, for example, this would add an optional index argument to the posts helper:

```
Template.home.helpers({
    posts(index) {
        if(typeof index !== "undefined" && index !== null){
            var data = Posts.find();
            return data[index];
        }
        else{
            return Posts.find();
        }    
    }
});
```

Then you set the data context and call it in blaze like this:

```
{{#with posts 0}}
    {{title}}
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just limit the size of the return set:

```
Template.home.helpers({
  posts() {
    return Posts.find({}, {limit: 1})
  }
});
```

Of course you'll probably want to `sort` it by something sensible as well, so that the first record is definitely the one you actually want.